# Checking Windows Disk Encryption with Pester

Tags: windows, powershell, pester

I am trying to test the Protection Status of local disks on Windows Server with Pester using the following Pester code:

```
Describe 'Encryption Check' {    
$Diskencr =  Get-BitLockerVolume

$Diskencr.ForEach{
    write-host $_.ProtectionStatus
    Context "Testing encryption on $($_)" {
        It "Encryption Enabled?" {$_.ProtectionStatus -match 'On' | Should -Be $True}
    }
}
```

}

The output shows 3 disks have "Protection Status" On and 1 is Off.

But the Pester "It check" says all are false and I do not know why?

```
    Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovering in D:\Temp\test.ps1.
On
Off
On
On
Found 4 tests. 2.44s
Discovery finished in 2.44s.

Running tests from 'D:\Temp\test.ps1'
Describing Encryption Check
 Context Testing encryption on E:
   [-] Encryption Enabled? 15ms (14ms|1ms)
    Expected $true, but got $false.
    at It "Encryption Enabled?" {$_.ProtectionStatus -match 'On' | Should -Be $True}, D:\Temp\test.ps1:7
    at <ScriptBlock>, D:\Temp\test.ps1:7
 Context Testing encryption on \\?\Volume{070ba12e-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
   [-] Encryption Enabled? 5ms (4ms|1ms)
    Expected $true, but got $false.
    at It "Encryption Enabled?" {$_.ProtectionStatus -match 'On' | Should -Be $True}, D:\Temp\test.ps1:7
    at <ScriptBlock>, D:\Temp\test.ps1:7
 Context Testing encryption on D:
   [-] Encryption Enabled? 8ms (6ms|2ms)
    Expected $true, but got $false.
    at It "Encryption Enabled?" {$_.ProtectionStatus -match 'On' | Should -Be $True}, D:\Temp\test.ps1:7
    at <ScriptBlock>, D:\Temp\test.ps1:7
 Context Testing encryption on C:
   [-] Encryption Enabled? 5ms (4ms|1ms)
    Expected $true, but got $false.
    at It "Encryption Enabled?" {$_.ProtectionStatus -match 'On' | Should -Be $True}, D:\Temp\test.ps1:7
    at <ScriptBlock>, D:\Temp\test.ps1:7
Tests completed in 2.72s
Tests Passed: 0, Failed: 4, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet, but im intreged by your question. I noticed that `$_` within the `It` is empty, so that is why it returns `$false`. Didn't find a solution for it yet though.

Comment: It turns out that in Pester v5 foreach loops works differently. Check this blog https://www.javydekoning.com/pester-5-scope-psscriptanalyzer/#how-to-do-it-in-v5

Comment: You are right! Thanks for the blog link, looks like I'll have to change the query a little. :)

Comment: As a side note - they added additional functionality to loop through a set of test cases at the describe and context level using the -ForEach syntax like ```Describe 'test something' -Foreach {...} ```
This is available in the current beta version.

Answer (score 0):

The **It** block isn't allowing scope to bleed into it.
It has to be reorganized into something like this, with the -TestCases argument

```
Describe 'Encryption Check' {
    Context "Testing encryption on drives" {
        It "checking a drive" -TestCases @(
            $Diskencr =  Get-BitLockerVolume
            $Diskencr.ForEach{
                @{ DriveLetter = $_ }
            }
        ) { 
            param($DriveLetter) 
                Write-Host $DriveLetter 
                $DriveLetter.ProtectionStatus -match 'On' | Should -BeExactly $True
        } 
    } 
}
```